# Regex and jQuery: lower case

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I would like to validate my form with jquery validation plugin.
I added a method for on input:

```
$.validator.addMethod("testRegex", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9-_]+$/i.test(value);
}, "test must contain only letters, numbers, underscores or dashes");
```

But I want a validation to check if the value is only lowercase. And This validation doesn't work.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: remove the `/i`.......

Comment: Haha, yeah remove /i, it means ignore case. :)

Comment: As an aside, if you're only going to allow lowercase your error message should say that too.

Answer (score 3):

The `i` in your regex means ignore case.  If you want your regular expression to be case sensitive then remove it.

```
/^[a-z0-9-_]+$/i
```

becomes

```
/^[a-z0-9-_]+$/
```

No `i` at end.